# htaccess redirect to subfolder with url paramethers

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string, friendly-url

I want to redirect every requests to my public/index.php file. i've tried

```
RewriteEngine On 
    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php?url=$1
```

code that seems fine but its not working. my goal is change url form http://example.com/?url=user/profile/2 to http://example.com/user/profile/2.
my directory structure is

- root

  - public

    - index.php
  - vendor
  - .htaccess
  - composer.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

heres the solution:
uncoment (remove `#` ) `mod_rewrite.so` module in httpd.conf file in apache2 (in my case c:\Apache24\conf\httpd.conf) file. also change `AllowOverride none` to `AllowOverride All` in that file under `DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs"` section.

and this is .htaccess content

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^()$ public/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

however if you need to get static files in your static directory add a new .htaccess file inside static directory with `RewriteEngine off` content

Answer (score 1):

To handle URLs like: `http://example.com/user/profile/2` please try following Rules sets in your .htaccess file. Place your htaccess rules file into root directory. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine ON
RedirectBase /ApadanaCMS/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/(.*)/?$ public/index.php?url=$1/$2/$3 [L]
```

---

---

OR try following rules, please make sure either try above OR following rules at a time only.

Above will work for non-existing pages, to make it for any url(like you mentioned in your question) try:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine ON
RedirectBase /ApadanaCMS/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/(.*)/?$ public/index.php?url=$1/$2/$3 [L]
```